# Does enabling coredump make my software debug build?

Tags: coredump, release-builds, debug-build, systemd-coredump

**Query**

This question is mainly oriented to Linux distributions.

Usually there are Debug and Release builds. Will my Release build become debug build if I enable coredumps.

**Reason for the query.**

We are having a very weird hard to reproducible issue which gets caught only in Release build and never in Debug build. Wanted to confirm if enabling coredumps make my release build as debug build and prevent me in catching the issue ? If not i will enable coredumps in my release build to check those cases.

Answer (score 0):

No.  Enabling core dumps (`ulimit -c unlimited`; systemd uses the  LimitCORE directive for this) is done prior to executing your binary, and has nothing to do with your build.